# Is it possible to XCTest text fields in a webview?

Tags: uiwebview, xctest, uitest

I have a webview in my app, but I need to do some UI Test, however I am unable to find the text field element to properly implement my test. Does anyone have any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You have to expose your HTML elements to the Accessibility. For the text field, you can do it this way.

```
<div id="text-input">Super</div>
<input type="text" aria-labelledby="text-input" value="empty" />
```

You should see something like this in the accessibility inspector
[image: Accessibility inspector preview]

This is how your test may look like.

```
func testExample()
{            
    let
    textField = app.webViews.textFields["Super"]
    textField.tap()

    let before = textField.value as? String
    XCTAssertEqual(before, "empty")

    // This is strange but without this sleep typeText method doesn't work
    sleep(1)

    textField.typeText("lorem ipsum")

    let after = textField.value as? String
    XCTAssertEqual(after, "emptylorem ipsum")
}
```

Generally, exposing HTML elements to the Accessibility is a difficult area. You can find a lot of examples [here](http://pauljadam.com/demos/). You can also check the [list of supported elements](http://pauljadam.com/demos/voiceover-ios-html-aria-support.html). Best of luck.

Comment: This answer does not appear to work. Using your example, the input does appear in the Accessibility Inspector as shown, however it's not found with `app.webViews.textFields["Super"].`

Answer (score 0):

If you have placeholder or text value in the input's of WKWebview instance, you can simply do

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
...
let webViewsQuery = app.webViews
let textfield1 = webViewsQuery.textFields["account email"]
viewExists = textfield1(timeout: 1.0)
if viewExists {
    textfield1.tap()
    sleep(1) // wait for keyboard
    textfield1.typeText("populated email value")

    let textfield2 = webViewsQuery.secureTextFields["Password"] // for password input type
    textfield2.tap()
    sleep(1) // wait for keyboard
    textfield2.typeText("populated password")
}
```